# Lenovo 501 - Configure WiFi Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I'm trying to get the driver for my WiFi card (`Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165`) to work.

Here the important bits of `dmesg`:

```
[    2.050033] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.051566] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.062248] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.098928] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 3165, REV=0x210
[    2.099766] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.100561] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.182739] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    2.230278] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    3.780426] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.781089] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.844792] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    3.845760] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    2.230278] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

[    3.780059] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    3.872703] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
[    3.959567] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

The blocks:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

The firmwares:

```
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-14.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-14.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-21.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8265-21.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8265-22.ucode
```

(I've already downloaded the ones from [intel support](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html))

My System:

```
Linux 4.4.0-65-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 23 17:49:58 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Current behavior:

I can see wireless networks, but if I want to connect, nothing happens.

Trying to connect produces these `dmesg` lines:

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

My syslog:

```
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1681] manager: (enp1s0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1702] keyfile: add connection in-memory (1f67fe56-6851-3584-9d98-b938033793bd,"Kabelnetzwerkverbindung 1")
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1707] settings: (enp1s0): created default wired connection 'Kabelnetzwerkverbindung 1'
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1714] device (enp1s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1847] device (lo): link connected
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1856] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1915] urfkill disappeared from the bus
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1945] bluez: use BlueZ version 5
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1956] ofono is now available
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <warn>  [1488516817.1961] failed to enumerate oFono devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.1964] ModemManager available in the bus
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.2243] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.2243] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.2693] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Mar  3 05:53:37 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516817.2693] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
Mar  3 05:53:40 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516820.5498] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
Mar  3 05:53:42 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516822.5502] manager: startup complete
Mar  3 05:53:47 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516827.5556] WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Mar  3 05:53:47 schaller-lenovo NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1488516827.5556] WWAN hardware radio set enabled
```

Trying to connect with `wpa_supplicant`:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 38:10:d5:98:34:23 (SSID='FRITZ!Box 3490' freq=5180 MHz)
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wlp2s0: Associated with 38:10:d5:98:34:23
wlp2s0: WPA: No SSID info found (msg 1 of 4)
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=38:10:d5:98:34:23 reason=0
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 38:10:d5:98:34:22 (SSID='FRITZ!Box 3490' freq=2412 MHz)
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wlp2s0: Associated with 38:10:d5:98:34:22
wlp2s0: WPA: No SSID info found (msg 1 of 4)
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=38:10:d5:98:34:22 reason=0
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 38:10:d5:98:34:23 (SSID='FRITZ!Box 3490' freq=5180 MHz)
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wlp2s0: Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=38:10:d5:98:34:23 reason=0
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 38:10:d5:98:34:22 (SSID='FRITZ!Box 3490' freq=2412 MHz)
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wlp2s0: Associated with 38:10:d5:98:34:22
wlp2s0: WPA: No SSID info found (msg 1 of 4)
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=38:10:d5:98:34:22 reason=0
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 38:10:d5:98:34:23 (SSID='FRITZ!Box 3490' freq=5180 MHz)
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wlp2s0: Associated with 38:10:d5:98:34:23
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=38:10:d5:98:34:23 reason=0
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="FRITZ!Box 3490" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="FRITZ!Box 3490"
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 38:10:d5:98:34:23 (SSID='FRITZ!Box 3490' freq=5180 MHz)
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wlp2s0: Associated with 38:10:d5:98:34:23
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=38:10:d5:98:34:23 reason=0
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="FRITZ!Box 3490" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="FRITZ!Box 3490"
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with 38:10:d5:98:34:23 (SSID='FRITZ!Box 3490' freq=5180 MHz)
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlp2s0: Association request to the driver failed
wlp2s0: Associated with 38:10:d5:98:34:23
wlp2s0: WPA: No SSID info found (msg 1 of 4)
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=38:10:d5:98:34:23 reason=0
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="FRITZ!Box 3490" auth_failures=3 duration=46 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

Which firmware files should I rename in order to have functioning wireless?

Comment: All the firmware is OK. The adapter should work. The problem is somewhere else, like router mac filter, etc.

Comment: @Pilot6 I thought so, but I don't know where to search for the problem

Comment: Please run in the terminal: `dmesg | grep -e wlp -e iwl`. Paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 I already did that; you can find the output in the first code block

Comment: Let's see: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n20` http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 I added the syslog and the output of wpa_supplicant